# Is it a good practice to end a mathematical equation with a comma or a period in a scientific article?

Tags: mathematics, writing, writing-style

I have noticed from different published articles that mathematical equations may or may not be ended by a comma or a period (depending on their position in the text).
Which is the best practice?

Comment: Looks like a web search could have solved this.

Comment: [Very, very relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6675)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, and as far as I understand one of the goals of SE is that the primary result of a web search will lead to a SE Q&A that addresses the query in question.

Comment: @LamarLatrell That was not my understanding; I thought that if a web search leads to, say, a Wikipedia page or some trustworthy reference that directly answers the question, there is no need to duplicate that information with an SE question.

Comment: @DavidZ, It's possible I have incorrect information on the matter, but my first thoughts were what if someone edits that Wiki or the webpage dies? (the same reasons why link only answers are frowned upon). Also, it may not affect you but my recent experience of living and working in a country with internet censorship has highlighted how helpful it has been for information to have levels of redundancy.

Comment: @LamarLatrell If we want to continue this discussion, I suppose it would be best to do it in chat or to raise the issue on meta so everyone can contribute

Comment: @DavidZ, I agree - however, I'd suggest that a meta discussion regarding this topic has probably been repeated on most SE sites (?) - but as for how to *find* it? No idea...  Also, as for how to start a chat, *no idea there either* (hence further polluting this comment stream with off-topic chat) - sorry all  :)

Comment: @LamarLatrell Not a problem, I've [created a chat room for us](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65704/discussion-between-david-z-and-lamar-latrell) in case you'd like to continue the discussion.

Comment: @LamarLatrell SE is not here to duplicate information on Wikipedia or similar. SE is here to collate information and to provide personalised answers to specific, personal questions. If it can be answered with a google search, the OP should have done more research.

Comment: @Tim, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65704/discussion-between-david-z-and-lamar-latrell

Comment: Is it a good thing to keep sticking to such rules when it's not necessary? If our ancestors had done that, we would still be speaking some ancient language with extremely complex grammar where besides  singular and plural forms for  nouns, pronouns, adjectives and verbs there also existed  dual, trial, quadral and paucal forms.

Comment: @LamarLatrell In any case, there are [already](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/for-formal-articles-should-a-displayed-equation-be-followed-by-a-punctuation-to) [several](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6675/periods-and-commas-in-mathematical-writing) [SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213952/when-writing-in-math-do-you-use-a-comma-or-colon-preceding-an-equation/2214408) [pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31124/should-there-be-a-period-after-an-equation) which answer this question.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, please read and contribute to the chat linked twice above.

Comment: One word: style guide for the publication. (I know that's more than one word but this is the academia SE, not the mathematics SE. ;-) ) I'm sure a search of math.stackexchange would find, if not this very question, one very similar.

Comment: Tautology 2.3.1 — A mathematical text is, before everything else, a text.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In-line formulas are punctuated as required by the grammar.  For displayed formulas there are two conventions: punctuate as required by the grammar; or no punctuation.  See if the journal specifies this in their style (most don't).  Example

> [image: jahnke_and_emde_-_dover_publications]

[Jahnke & Emde, Dover Publications]

Comment: I wouldn't take a German text as an example to back up your claim: different languages may have different conventions here, and German, in particular, notoriously has different rules than English for comma placement.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You didn't notice that the text was bilingual?

Comment: @MrLister No, I didn't, but that makes it even weirder as an example. Mathematical conventions do not translate well among languages (case in point: that decimal comma). It's not like there is a shortage of mathematical texts in English that OP could have used instead...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni No, it doesn't make it weirder; on the contrary, it shows that formulas are simply part of the sentence structure, _no matter the language_.

Comment: @MrLister No, it shows that they were treated that way in this example of a bilingual text. There's no reason to assume the convention followed in English is the same as in German, and if they're not then the fact that this uses "," as a decimal separator suggests German conventions are being preferred over English. This *is* how I've always treated them, but nevertheless I agree with Federico that this is a very poor choice of example to illustrate that.

Comment: Also, seeing as there is no comma after *following* as one would expect in English ("In the following, *n* signifies. . .") I am even less confident of the value of this particular example.

Answer (score 27):

The practice I'm familiar with is that equations are part of the text, and end with a period if they are the end of the sentence and with a comma or other punctuation mark if the sentence continues and calls for it.

Comment: Yes, that's a common approach. In other words, think of offset formulas as if they were part of the regular sentence structure. You will then know how to terminate them: with a period, if they end a sentence; and a comma, a semicolon, or nothing if the sentence continues in some way.

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma just because the sentence continues; there should only be a comma if one is required in that position in the sentence.

Comment: And, in some cases, there could be other punctuation ... colon, question mark, etc.  Whatever is required by the grammar.

Comment: @GEdgar : I agree, if $3 = 3$!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is good practice. You should read the papers of people are well known to be excellent expositors like Serre and his students Atiyah and Grothendieck (who also had quite a few students). They all endorse commas and periods. Perhaps the best guide to mathematical writing is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECQyFzzBHlo (Serre). Let me emphasize how  authoritative  Serre's opinion is: he is easily the most influential mathematician of the postwar period.